# Very Light Posts

Tags: support, questions

Every once in a while (once in a day or two days) a post is rendered in white type on a white background.

This one, for example:

[Screen randomly flickering on Linux Mint](https://superuser.com/questions/1548201/screen-randomly-flickering-on-linux-mint)

Why are a small number of posts rendered unreadable?

Here is a screen shot of the example. This was done in Windows 10 and I used Chrome as a commonly used browser.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the tags screen you wished to see. I do not recall being in this screen any time in the recent past.

[image]

Comment: The linked question is completely readable

Comment: If you want this bug report to be taken seriously.  You need to indicate what browser you are using.

Comment: Is it tagged with a tag that you have ignored?

Comment: Screenshots would be useful. It apparently is not happening for anyone else.

Comment: @John - You can edit a closed question.  You will have to be more specific than saying it happens with Chrome or Edge.  “Newest” could mean many things, given Chrome for instance, has 3 active versions currently

Comment: I did not answer or comment on that post. but pulling up the answer someone else gave renders the entire thing readable. So opening a light post renders it readable, but not when just viewing a list of posts. Thanks

Comment: This really looks as if you were ignoring at least one of the tags.

Comment: I did not do anything in the post I linked to so no tabs tags there

Comment: What do you see in [this list](https://superuser.com/users/tag-notifications/1079976#ignored-3)? (the link should be available only to you).

Comment: No tags of any kind. I just do not use tags at all. Decent thought, but I do not use them.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of https://superuser.com/users/tag-notifications/1079976 what you are seeing is exactly the behaviour of an ignored tag.

Comment: I have done as you asked me to do. Thanks.

Comment: So now it's clear that you do have one ignored tag and that's why that post looks that way.

Comment: I am not sure how that happened but I cleared and we will see what happens. That may be the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As other users have noted in the comments, this is because you have ignored the [display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display) tag and this question is tagged with it. You have the choice to either gray they out (your current setting) or hide them completely. As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321052/295232), you can go to the "Ignored Tags" widget in the right sidebar (shown on all pages with question lists, including the [home page](https://superuser.com/)) and change your setting there:

[image]

In extreme cases, this might lead to strange situations like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png), but probably only if you ignore a lot of tags.

Comment: That has happened to me as well in the past. I'm not blaming you, just providing some general guidance in case somebody else has this problem too :)

Comment: No one is saying you did it on purpose @John, but several people were telling you the exact cause and rather than saying "Okay, so how do I fix it?" you were like "Nah, that can't be my problem..." which leads people down the garden path assuming you know *for certain* that it is not that. That makes it difficult to help you. Chances are that at some point you clicked on the [tag:display] tag and, whether by accident or act of pets, you clicked [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3XeV.png).